# ReactJS: Как передать аргумент в обработчик событий?

Tags: reactjs

Допустим, компонент имеет обработчик события:

```
onClick={this.handleClick}
```

Функция обработчиков всегда принимает на вход "синтетический" event.

```
handleClick(e){
  //...
}
```

**Вопрос:** Как передать свой аргумент в обработчик и обратиться к аргументу в нем (есть ли такая возможность)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, использовать [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, ev)}
```